Issue With TForm.AlphaBlend and AlphaBlendValue
In my Delphi project, the availability of some features depends on the user's licence. So, a Basic licence will not allow access to Advanced features. However, I want Basic licence users to see what they are missing by placing a "No Entry" form over the restricted part of the application. I have a form with a No Entry sign and a couple of TLabels. The No Entry form has an AlphaBlendValue = 100 so that it is translucent - the user can see what's behind it and the two TLabels tell them what they are missing and what to do about it.
This is working nicely except for one thing: the AlphaBlendValue is having no effect so the form displays completely opaque (the user cannot see what is underneath).
I cannot upload my project because it is confidential and simply way too big. I have tried for many hours to reproduce this issue in various test projects but have been unable to do so - they all work perfectly!!
So, I can only conclude that there is some aspect of my project that is causing the No Entry form to display 100% opaque. I have wasted many hours changing things (pure trial and error), but nothing helped.
My only hope is that someone here has experienced the same (or similar) issue and managed to discover the cause.
Or, perhaps I am going about this the wrong way and there is a better solution?
Delphi 12.2 Enterprise
Windows 11 Professional
Here is the unit for the No Entry form:
unit NoEntryForm;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, SVGIconImage, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.Classes, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type

  INoEntryForm = interface
    ['{085FB8DC-3E21-4A50-B4CC-006E9872BF62}']
    procedure ShowMe;
  end;


  /// <summary>
  /// A "no entry" panel to be displayed when a user attempts to access a feature to which their application licence does not permit access.
  /// It is intended to encourage the user to upgrade by showing them a glimpse of what they are missing.
  /// </summary>
  TfrmNoEntry = class(TForm, INoEntryForm)
    imgNoEntry: TSVGIconImage;
    pnlTop: TPanel;
    lblNoEntry: TLabel;
    lblPleaseUpgrade: TLabel;
    procedure ShowMe;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure ShowNoEntry(const strMessage: string; const ctlParent: TWinControl; const strCaption: string);

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

/// <summary>
/// Displays a "No Entry" form over the given control (ctlParent)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="strMessage">Message to the user (typically something about having to upgrade to access the inaccessible feature)</param>
/// <param name="ctlParent">The TWinControl descendant on which the No Entry form should be displayed (eg a TPanel for example)</param>
/// <param name="strCaption">The No Entry form's caption (typically "No Entry")</param>
procedure ShowNoEntry(const strMessage: string; const ctlParent: TWinControl; const strCaption: string);
begin
  for var i := 0 to ctlParent.ControlCount - 1 do begin
    if ctlParent.Controls[i] is TfrmNoEntry then
      exit;   // ctlParent already has a TfrmNoEntry so we can stop here
  end;

  var frmNoEntry := TfrmNoEntry.Create(nil);
  var FormInterface: INoEntryForm := frmNoEntry;

  frmNoEntry.Parent := ctlParent;
  frmNoEntry.TransparentColor := false;
  frmNoEntry.AlphaBlend := True;
  frmNoEntry.AlphaBlendValue := 100;
  frmNoEntry.Align := alNone;
  frmNoEntry.BoundsRect := ctlParent.BoundsRect;
  frmNoEntry.Anchors := [akLeft,akTop,akRight,akBottom];
  frmNoEntry.lblNoEntry.Caption := strCaption;
  frmNoEntry.lblPleaseUpgrade.Caption := strMessage;
  frmNoEntry.ShowMe;
end;

procedure TfrmNoEntry.ShowMe;
begin
  Show;
end;

end.

So, in my project if I need to display a No Entry form on top of Panel1 I just call ShowNoEntry;
ShowNoEntry('Text explaining why access is denied', Panel1, 'No Entry!');


Update: a user on Delphi-PRAXiS has given me the solution.
https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/12268-issue-with-tformalphablend-and-alphablendvalue/
My project needed a manifest with a compatibility entry for Windows 10.
